# Printing out python tree from nested list and flat list

Tags: python, tree

I want to define two functions, one that prints a tree out from a nested list and the other that prints a tree from a flat list.

For exaple, if we have the lists
`[5, [10, None, None], [11, [2, None, None],[6, None, None]]],`
 and `[None, 5, 10, 11, None, None, 2, 6]`, we would produce a tree that looks like

```
 10
    5
    15
        11
        22
```

This is the Binary Tree implementation

```
class BinaryTree:

def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

def get_left(self):
    return self.left

def get_right(self):
    return self.right

def set_left(self, tree):
    self.left = tree

def set_right(self, tree):
    self.right = tree

def set_data(self, data):
    self.data = data

def get_data(self):
    return self.data

def create_string(self, spaces): 
    info = ' ' * spaces + str(self.data) 
    if self.left != None: 
        info += self.left.create_string(spaces+4) 
    if not self.right == None: 
        info += self.right.create_string(spaces+4) 
    return info       

def __str__(self): 
    representation = self.create_string(0) 
    return representation
```

I basically want to convert the list into a tree because there is a create string function in the Binary Tree class

Comment: What output are you getting and what difficulty are you having?

Comment: What is the algorithm for converting the flat list to a tree structure?

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive function would allow you to create the nested lists into a btree:

```
def create_tree(data):
    if not data:
        return data
    d, l, r = data
    btree = BinaryTree(d)
    btree.set_left(create_tree(l))
    btree.set_right(create_tree(r))
    return btree

>>> print(create_tree([10, [5, None, None], [15, [11, None, None],[22, None, None]]]))
10
(l)    5
(r)    15
(l)        11
(r)        22
```

Though personally I would update the `__init__()` method of the `BinaryTree` class to optionally take the left and right:

```
class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

Then the recursive function becomes:

```
def create_tree(data):
    if not data:
        return data
    d, l, r = data
    return BinaryTree(d, create_tree(l), create_tree(r))
```

It's unclear what the mapping from the flat list is to the tree structure.